# Displaying menu over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sliding menu that should be displayed over an image, actually a logo. However, when it does, it is shifted as if the text of the menu wanted to avoid touching the image.

See :

[the problem in image http://fruityhotchocolate.com/m.png](http://fruityhotchocolate.com/m.png)

(note: the website is in french)

I deal with the event as follows:

```
$("nav>#menu>ul>li").hover(function(e) {
    $("ul",this).css("display","block");
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `position:absotule` in the menu.

Comment: First go without hiding the submenus, then style them the way you want on hover, then hide the submenu items. Also take a look at http://www.cssmenus.co.uk/dropdown.html to see how dropdowns can be implmented, you need a guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript, you can do it with CSS:

Add the following code:

```
#menu>ul>li>ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu>ul>li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Moreover, you should use child selectors (`>`) instead of descendant selectors:

```
#menu>ul
#menu>ul>li>ul
#menu>ul>li>ul>li
#menu>ul>li>ul>li>a
#menu>ul>li>a, #menu>ul>li>a:hover, #menu>ul>li>a:visited
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what happens is that the `li` expands to the same width as the `ul` because it does not have a fixed width. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu ul').children('li').each(function () {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).css('width'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with CSS:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png​​​​​​​​​​" />
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
CSS:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.content:hover .menu {
    display: block;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nfKc4/